# Link a cell in a table view controller to a webpage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a Table View Controller with multiple cells. How can I link the cells to a webpage? I was thinking about linking them to another view controller with a Web View but it would take long because I have many cells to link. How can I link a cell to a webpage?

Comment: What you mean by linking cells to webpage ?

Answer (score 2):

In your didSelectRow method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
{
    NSString * urlString = [self.yourArrayWithLinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not link cells to something. You react to the [didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] method of UITableViewDelegate